# Can PropertyGrid customise display for different selected objects values, instead of blank?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Is is possible to customise the display value of a property when the selected objects have different values for the property?

The default behaviour of the grid is to show a value when all selected objects have the same value, but simply blank the field when they differ.  There is no way of knowing *how* they differ.

Eg given the following classes and code, is it possible to configure the inspector and class to display something like the following (a range for integer values, multiple for anything else)

```
TestLong|[50 - 60]
 TestInt|10
TestEnum|[Multiple]
```

ie if the values differ show something indicating how they differ, but if they are all the same show that value?

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    EnumVal1,
    EnumVal2,
    EnumVal3
}

public class TestClass
{
    public long TestLong { get; set; }
    public int TestInt { get; set; }
    public TestEnum TestEnum { get; set; }
}

    ...
control.SelectedObjects = new []
{
    new TestClass 
    { 
        TestLong = 50, 
        TestInt = 10, 
        TestEnum = TestEnum.EnumVal1 
    },
    new TestClass 
    { 
        TestLong = 60, 
        TestInt = 10, 
        TestEnum = TestEnum.EnumVal3
    },
}
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change the display because the PropertyGrid general uses [TypeConverters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) (including implicit ones) to display the value, but for multiple selection, it's not used.

What you could do though, but it's not exactly the answer, is propose a custom [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx) when the grid is in multiselection mode, like this:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        // decorate the property with a custom UITypeEditor
        [Editor(typeof(MyMultiSelectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public long TestLong { get; set; }
        public int TestInt { get; set; }
        public TestEnum TestEnum { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyMultiSelectionEditor : UITypeEditor
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            // adapt to your need
            if (!IsPropertyGridInMultiView(context))
                return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;

            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }

        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            if (IsPropertyGridInMultiView(context))
            {
                // multi view, show my custom stuff
                MessageBox.Show("hello from multi selection");
            }
            return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
        }

        // gets a PropertyGrid instance from the context, if any
        private static PropertyGrid GetPropertyGrid(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            IServiceProvider sp = context as IServiceProvider;
            if (sp == null)
                return null;

            Control view = sp.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as Control;
            if (view == null)
                return null;

            return view.Parent as PropertyGrid;
        }

        // determines if there is a PropertyGrid in the context, and if it's selection is multiple
        private static bool IsPropertyGridInMultiView(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            PropertyGrid pg = GetPropertyGrid(context);
            if (pg == null)
                return false;

            return pg.SelectedObjects != null && pg.SelectedObjects.Length > 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. I've tried this, and while it is useful, it's not quite what I need.  I'd like to customise the display value _before_ editing it.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, although not as I had originally intended.

The root cause of the problem was that the TypeConverters were not being applied when there were multiple selected objects.  To solve it, I introduced an aggregate class, that did aggregation of the individual objects, but gets presented as a single object.  That way, the TypeConverter can get called.

Sample code (hacked version of real production code) is below:

```
public interface ISupportAggregate
{
    object[] Individuals { get; }
}

public class AggregateTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public const string MULTIPLE = @"[multiple]";

    private TypeConverter mTypeConverter;

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        Initialize(context);

        if (context != null && destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            var aggregate = context.Instance as ISupportAggregate;
            if (aggregate != null && IsDifferingItems(context.PropertyDescriptor.Name, aggregate.Individuals))
            {
                return MULTIPLE;
            }
        }
        return mTypeConverter.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public static bool IsDifferingItems(string propertyName, object[] items)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor itemProperty = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(items[0].GetType())[propertyName];
        return items.Select(itemProperty.GetValue).Distinct().Count() > 1;
    }

    private void Initialize(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        if (mTypeConverter == null)
            mTypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(context.PropertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
    }

    #region Calling through to mTypeConverter

    public override object CreateInstance(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Collections.IDictionary propertyValues)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.CreateInstance(context, propertyValues);
    }

    public override bool GetCreateInstanceSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.GetCreateInstanceSupported(context);
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
    }

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.GetPropertiesSupported(context);
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.GetStandardValues(context);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.GetStandardValuesExclusive(context);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.GetStandardValuesSupported(context);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.IsValid(context, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        return mTypeConverter.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class AggregateTestClass : TestClass
{
    private readonly TestClass[] mObjects;

    public AggregateTestClass(TestClass[] objects)
    {
        mObjects = objects;
    }

    protected override object[] GetIndividuals()
    {
        return mObjects;
    }
}

public class TestClass : ISupportAggregate
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(AggregateTypeConverter))]
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(AggregateTypeConverter))]
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public object[] Individuals
    {
        get { return GetIndividuals(); }
    }

    virtual protected object[] GetIndividuals()
    {
        return new[] { this };
    }
}

public class TestSupportAggregate : ISupportAggregate, TestClass
{
    private readonly TestClass[] mItems;

    public TestSupportAggregate(TestClass[] items)
    {
        mItems = items;
    }

    public object[] Individuals
    {
        get { return mItems; }
    }
}


To use in code:

control.SelectedObject = new TestSupportAggregate(new[]
                                                 {
                                                     new TestClass { IntProperty = 5150 },
                                                     new TestClass { IntProperty = 1984 }
                                                 });
```